# How to characterize $E_n$ morphisms from $\mathrm{Mod}(A)$ to $\mathrm{Mod}(B)$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories, operads, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $E_{\infty}$ rings, then $\mathrm{Mod}(A)$ and $\mathrm{Mod}(B)$ are $E_{\infty}$ monoidal categories (left modules over those rings). We can ask about $E_n$ colimit-preserving morphisms between these two categories. How do we characterize them? If $n=\infty$ we just have maps from $A$ to $B$ and if we don't ask for any monoidal compatibility I guess we just get bimodules over $A$ and $B$, but what are the intermediates? Maybe we can also ask for a characterization of $E_n$ maps of the category of $E_n$ modules over $E_n$ rings?

Edit: Thanks to Dylan's answer below the first question is solved. However I believe the second question is still not answered, which is about studying $E_n$ maps between categories of $E_n$ modules over $E_n$ rings.

Comment: I suppose one way to characterize them is as algebras over a colored operad. Does this help?

Comment: Do you require your morphisms to preserve colimits ? And also, when you say $E_n$-morphisms, do you mean morphisms of $E_n$-operads (i.e. lax $E_n$-monoidal functors), or of $E_n$-categories ("strong" $E_n$-monoidal functors)? In the case of lax $E_n$-monoidal colimit-preserving functors, you can extend the bimodule characterization. Note, by the way, that over an $E_n$ ring $A$, you can only expect $Mod_A$ to be $E_{n-1}$-monoidal, not $E_n$.

Comment: Under some continuity conditions, surely Eilenberg--Watts will characterize these as the E_{n+1} morphisms from A to B?

Comment: Yes I would like co-continuous functors, I'll edit. Everything I would like to be nonstrict, but I'm not sure about your definitions of lax vs strong. doesn't lax mean that the tensor product doesn't need to be preserved but just there exists a map?

Comment: Ok so I'm a bit confused about the commutativeness of modules over $E_n$ algebras. If I take a $E_2$ ring, then left modules over it is $E_1$ right? What happens if I take $E_2$ modules over it? Is it $E_2$ or is there no monoidal structure at all? Sorry I'm new to this stuff

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I also guessed something like this, but I'm coming short on a reference? can you provide a version of the theorem quoted which applies here

Comment: @AndyJiang Indeed, the category of E_n-modules over an E_n-algebra is E_n-monoidal; this is HA.3.3.3.9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Corollary HA.4.8.5.20, the functor from $\mathbb{E}_{n+1}$-algebras to $\mathbb{E}_n$-monoidal categories and colimit-preserving, $\mathbb{E}_n$-monoidal functors is fully faithful. (Notice that the condition of being "linear over Sp" is automatic from exactness). So, indeed, you'd get just $\mathbb{E}_{n+1}$-algebra maps $A \to B$.

Added:

I just wrote down the reference, but of course, as Ben-Zvi points out, this should be relatively intuitive. First of all, building a functor $F:\mathsf{RMod}_A \to \mathcal{C}$ means that I'd better tell you how $A=\mathrm{End}_A(A)$ acts on $F(A)$, and you can kinda see that that is all I need to do if $F$ commutes with colimits (because I can start resolving by free modules and I understand what to do with all the maps). In other words, I need to provide an algebra map $A \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(F(A))$. So now we believe that $A \mapsto \mathsf{RMod}_A$, viewed as a functor to categories equipped with a distinguised object, has a right adjoint given by $(\mathcal{C},c)\mapsto \mathrm{End}(c)$.

The functor $A \mapsto \mathsf{RMod}_A$ turns out to be symmetric monoidal when one views its values as landing in, say, stable, presentable categories, and so its right adjoint will be lax symmetric monoidal. It follows that we get an induced adjunction on categories of algebras, and that the endomorphism object of the unit in an $\mathbb{E}_n$-monoidal category is canonically $\mathbb{E}_{n+1}$-monoidal (you can think of that like: you get an $\mathbb{E}_1$-algebra structure from composing, and then an $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebra structure from tensoring, so together you get an $\mathbb{E}_{n+1}$-algebra structure).

All together, then, to specify an $\mathbb{E}_n$-monoidal functor $\mathsf{RMod}_A \to \mathcal{C}$, I just need an $\mathbb{E}_{n+1}$-algebra map $A \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(1)$.

There's some other discussion about how to describe maps between categories of $\mathbb{E}_n$-modules, but I think that's not as clear to me... Yes, it's true that the endomorphisms of the unit in the category of $\mathbb{E}_n$-modules is the $\mathbb{E}_n$-center, but if the source of our functor is some other category of $\mathbb{E}_n$-modules (as opposed to ordinary modules over something $\mathbb{E}_{n+1}$), then our argument above doesn't apply.

Comment: (I guess this is also stated, explicitly for $\mathbb{E}_n$ as opposed to other operads, as HA.5.1.2.6)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you also say something about the question in the last sentence? About En maps between categories of En modules over En rings? Should I think of them as some sort of bimodules or? (I guess in retrospect the two questions I asked are not entirely similar)

Comment: It might be worth spelling out that the idea here is simple: the endomorphisms of the unit in an $E_n$-monoidal category is an $E_{n+1}$-algebra, which is how we recover the algebra from its category of modules -- same as looking at $E_0$ (ie pointed) functors between categories of modules of ordinary (associative) algebras. @AndyJiang you should then apply this reasoning to the category of $E_n$-modules, and you get the center ($E_n$ Hochschild cohomology) of your algebra -- e.g. in the $E_1$ case endomorphisms of $A$ as $A-A$-bimodule.

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi yes, good point! However, I'm a little confused about your generalization to E_n-modules. It's definitely true that the endomorphism object of the unit is the E_n-center, but that would only help me if I wanted to build an E_n-map from, say, LMod_A to Mod^{E_n}_B. If I wanted to build a map from Mod^{E_n}_A then it's not so clear (I can't just say "oh, use LMod_{U^{(n)}(A)}" because the E_n-monoidal structure on that does not come from 'tensor over U^n(A)' but rather from tensoring over A). Have I made an error here?

Comment: I was just thinking that E_n modules for A has as a full E_n subcategory containing the unit a copy of left modules for the E_{n+1} algebra which is the center of A, right? so if I have an E_n monoidal functor out of it to say E_n modules over B I get out of that an E_{n+1} map between the centers.

Comment: I guess one thing missing is are we always in an "affine" situation, ie. are E_n-A-modules generated by the unit? you're pointing out the whole category is left modules over the enveloping algebra of A, which is a different statement right?

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi I agree that *if* you have an E_n-monoidal functor then you get an E_{n+1}-map between the centers, but it doesn't seem to me like you can go the other way round (but maybe I'm missing something). For your second question, I guess a good test case would be bimodules: are A-bimodules generated by A? It doesn't seem to me like they are (e.g. for A=k[x] you're asking for k[x,y]-modules to be generated by k[x,y]/(x-y) which doesn't seem true, does it?)

Comment: (like- it's the difference between left modules over the enveloping algebra and left modules over the center)

Comment: @DylanWilson Right - in that case you'd want something like A Artin local. So presumably there's a similar class of E_n algebras for which this argument works, but unclear that that's of much interest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To clarify my comment: suppose you're interested in lax $E_n$-monoidal functor (so that indeed, you get coherent maps $F(M)\otimes F(N)\to F(M\otimes N)$ which aren't necessarily equivalences, similarly for $1\to F(1)$) that preserve colimits, then the category of such functors is essentially $Alg_{E_n}(Fun^{ex}(Mod_A^\omega,Mod_B))$ where $Fun^{ex}(Mod_A^\omega, Mod_B)$ has a symmetric monoidal structure induced by the Day convolution structure on $Fun(Mod_A^\omega, Mod_B)$.

Then you get a symmetric monoidal identification $Mod_{A^{op}\otimes B} \simeq Fun(Mod_A^\omega,Mod_B)$ which, since $A$ is $E_\infty$, can be thought of as $Mod_{A\otimes B}$.

Therefore lax $E_n$-monoidal colimit preserving functors $Mod_A\to Mod_B$ can be thought of as $E_n-A\otimes B$-algebras.

Of course, these rarely classify strict monoidal functors (those where $F(M)\otimes F(N)\to F(M\otimes N)$ *is* an equivalence, and $1\to F(1)$ is as well). In fact they do if and only if this $A\otimes B$-module is $B$ with structure induced from an $E_{n+1}$-map $A\to B$: Tyler's answer shows this.

I made a silly comment below Tyler's answer (then deleted, as I realized my mistake), which is perhaps noteworthy: if you try to take this approach and check when, for an $A\otimes B$-module $R$, the associated lax $E_n$-monoidal functor is actually strict, you'll get two conditions: one on the map $F(M)\otimes F(N)\to F(M\otimes N)$ and one on the unit. The second one is easy to forget (which is what happened in my silly comment), and if you do, you'll get something like an $E_n-B$-algebra such that the structure map $B\to R$ is an epimorphism.

This is why for instance $Mod_\mathbb Q\to Sp$ is almost symmetric monoidal, although it is only lax: you get the condition on tensor products but not the one on the unit.